# filter in kendoUI drag and drop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a splitter. In this splitter, I am implementing drag and drop functionality for the list view. Each list view is loaded in "table" format.

I want to drag my list view from left to right.

For the 1st list view, I have this code :

```
var listViewOptions = {
    template: kendo.template(
        $("#Firsttemplate").html()
    ),
    dataSource: listdatSource,
}; 

var sourceListView = $("#First").kendoListView(listViewOptions).data("kendoListView");

var draggableOptions = {
    filter: "table",
    hint: function (e) {
        return $('<div class="new">' + e.html() + '</div>');
    }
}

sourceListView.element.kendoDraggable(draggableOptions);
```

In the filter, if I give "table" / "tbody" the whole content of list view is dragging in a row format and after dropping it is in the right side of splitter and is displaying in a single row. I want to display in the same format as in the leftside.

Can you tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`somejQueryElement.html()` gives you the inner HTML code of your element. Thus, if you filter on table elements, your argument `e` of the `hint` function is the table and `e.html()` is the content of the table.

If you want to have your table, you have to add reencapsulate the element in `table` tags :

```
var draggableOptions = {
    filter: "table",
    hint: function (e) {
        return $('<div class="new"><table>' + e.html() + '</table></div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel,Its working fine.can i add another field to the draggable content.actually I have two fields in 1st listview and after dragging it I want to add one more field to this and display three fields after drop it in the right side of splitter.

Comment: In the field `filter`, you can put any jQuery selector. So if the element that you want to drag is encapsulate in a div with some specific class, you can specify : `filter: "your-class-name"`.